# Java Regex: Evaluate a string against a particular pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have strings of a particular pattern as below which i need to validate:

```
String a ="test/<value>"
String b = "test/test1/<value>"
String c = "test3";
String d = "test4"
```

where **value** - can be any thing i.e alphabets,numeric,symbol,spl characters.

String c and String d are pretty straight forward.The issue comes for string a,b.

Valid Strings:

```
test/12 | test/abc | test/12.39 ...
test/test1/12 | test/test1/abc | test/test1/12.30
test3
test4
```

Invalid Strings:

```
test1/12
test/test123/12
```

test,test1,test3,test4 are key words. any change in that should return me false.

I tried with the below regex pattern:

```
Pattern  pattern1 = "^(test/(test1/)?[A-Za-z0-9]+|test3|test4)?/?$"
```

it works fine for few scenario's i.e

```
test/123 (pass)
test/test1/abc123(pass)
```

It fails when it has any symbol,decimal value or spl characters:

```
test/10.12 (Fail)
test/test1/@#$$ (Fail)

Pattern pattern2 = "^(test/(test1/)?[A-Za-z0-9/*!@#$%^&*()\"{}_|\\?/<>,.]+|test3|test4)?/?$";
```

When i use the above pattern if there are any change in the keyword it fails.

```
test/test1344/123(Fail)
```

i.e even if i change the keyword it returns as true.Expected result is false.

Please advice as to how i can validate the above strings ?

Comment: I think a tokenizer is more appropriate in your case, as it looks like you're using slash delimited tokens, and each token determines the valid values of the next one.

Comment: Do i understand correctly that your problem is that the second part can be anything but a variation of test1? Like, you can have test/foo, but not test/test12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:test/(?:test1/)?[^/]+|test3|test4)/?$
```

I just replaced `[A-Za-z0-9]` by `[^/]` (any non forward slash character)

Comment: I think the problem is that he wants to also forbid things like  test/test1344/123, while allowing test/test2FOOOO

Comment: The keywords(test,test/test1,test3,test4) are static and what ever is after keyword can have any value.

Comment: @anubhava. Thanks it works. It would be great it you can explain the expression.

Comment: Most of the regex was taken from your question. I am using `[^/]` which means match anything except a forward slash. More importantly I removed `?` just before closing `/?$` from your regex otherwise regex could even match an empty string or just `/`. Finally I used `?:` for non capturing group (not important).

Comment: Just a side note: Depending on what you want, this might not be enough, as it still allows test/test123

Comment: @kutschkem: I don't think `test/test123` is invalid input (as per OP).

Answer (score 0):

Try `^(test3|test4|test(/test1)?/([0-9.]+|[A-Za-z]+))$/` .

Comment: it fails when the value is "test/123"  
   
 `String test= "^(test3|test4|test(/test1)?/([0-9.]+|[A-Za-z]+))$/";`

    `String name1="test/12";`

    `final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(test);`

    `final boolean isValid = p.matcher(name1).matches();

have i missed something ?`

Comment: No, I wrongly added a trailing slash. Remove that and it should work. Also, try one of the many online regex building tools, such as http://txt2re.com/